# How to make a login system like that of facebook

Tags: php, security, cookies

I have a enquiry, now this was a serious brainstorming problem for me. Do one thing at first, go to m.facebook.com from your phone, then login, then login from a computer and change the password from that computer, while changing the password, you are asked weather or not to deauthenticate the device that you are previously logged in with. if you choose keep them logged in, then again open fb from phone, then you don't need to login again, now the question is HOW? Because if fb don't store the hashed password in the cookie, then what does it store and yet it is secured? Anyone know about this login authentication system?

Comment: **Never encrypt passwords**.  Passwords should be **hashed** with a secure, salted, iterated, algorithm.

Comment: Security is _hard_.  Don't re-invent the wheel; you are very likely to make bad mistakes.  You should use an existing implementation.

Comment: sorry, i was talking about hashing, mistakely i wrote encrypt.

Comment: You still shouldn't re-invent the wheel.  This is very hard to get right.

Comment: any ideas how do you do that? and can you refer to any of the existing implementation?

Comment: What language and server are you using?  Search Google for login systems.

Comment: im using php and apache, i googled but cant find, can you provide me a link?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18641/discussion-between-nicholas-wild-and-slaks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB is probably using a cookie that has a very long lifetime.  This cookie's value is large random number that is used to pull information from a database.

Storing a password hash in the cookie is vulnerability that is so stupid it hurts my eyes just reading it.  [Its also something I have exploited in the wild](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/12510/).

Comment: thanks, that was the point i thought, the large random number... thanks a lot...